# constructor and object - interview

Tags: java, c++

This is the question asked in the interview. What does `foo a` and `foo a()` denotes in the below coding snippet.

```
class foo
    {
        foo a;
        foo a();
    }
```

what does foo a and foo a() will do? Interviewers did not mention whether this is java or c++. They wanted me to give answers in both C++ and Java.

Comment: This is a basic java question. Try reading the Java Tutorial (google search "Java Tutorial") for the answer. This is also a trick question since in the context of this class, foo a(); is a syntax error in java.

Comment: This is not valid C++...

Comment: It is not valid Java either...

Comment: @MikeRylander: It's neither, for reasons explained in my answer. :)

Comment: @NPE I see. Why is this question tagged for Java ***and*** C++?

Comment: @MikeRylander: No idea! I ended up answering for both, because my original monolingual answer was getting downvoted into oblivion... :)

Comment: Hey guys. Actually the interviewer did not say whether it is java or c++. I asked them but they replied it is for both. So, i tagged it in both.

Comment: Guys, Can anyone upvote this question? I could not post anymore questions now as there 5 downvote for this. Actually this question showed in couple of interviews and i thought it might be helpful.

Comment: @MikeRylander Guys, Can anyone upvote this question? I could not post anymore questions now as there 5 downvote for this. Actually this question showed in couple of interviews and i thought it might be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

In C++, the first line is an error (a class can't contain an instance of itself). The second line declares a method that returns an instance of `foo` by value. There's also a missing semicolon at the end.

In Java, the first line declares a data member that is a reference to `foo`. The second line is an error since the method must have a body.

In summary, it's not valid code in either of the two languages. :-)

Comment: @jrok: Yeah, it took a little while to spot the confused tags :)

Comment: C++ also requires a semicolon after the class definition.

Comment: In C++ foo * a; wud have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, it's not correct Java-wise. Others have explained that.

Assuming it's pseudocode, however, I imagine the basic answer would be something like:

`foo a;` is a variable named `a` of type `foo`.

`foo a();` is a method named `a` that returns an object of type `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo a;
```

declares a *field* `a` which is a reference to `foo`.

```
foo a();
```

is an error in Java. This is a *method* declaration (method without body). In Java such an abstract method must be qualified with `abstract` keyword:

```
abstract foo a();
```

This declares an *abstract* method `a` which returns `foo` reference. Every class definition which contains an abstract method *declaration* must be qualified with `abstract` keyword itself. In your case the class declaration should look like:

```
abstract class foo {
```

From Java Language Specification - [**§8.1.1.1**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1):

> Normal classes may have abstract methods, that is,
>   methods that are declared but not yet implemented, only if they are
>   abstract classes. If a normal class that is not abstract contains an
>   abstract method, then a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Its a method that will return type foo, since class is not abstract compiler will throw error

Comment: Poor quality answer which is better worded in other answers, and only addresses part of the question. I suggest a delete.

Answer (score 0):

For Java

```
class foo
    {
        foo a;
        foo a();
    }
```

The first line declares a reference to a "foo" object with the name of "a".  The value will be null.

The second line is an error.  It is trying to declare a method called "a" that returns a "foo" but there is no body to the method.  The class and the method would need to be declared abstract for this to work, or the "a" method would have to be given a body.